# On a source for a mean-variance portfolio optimization result

Tags: portfolio-management, modern-portfolio-theory, portfolio-optimization

In the context of a mean_variance framework consider an optimizing investor who chooses at time $T$ portfolio weights $w$ so as to maximize the quadratic objective function:

$$U(w) = E[R_p] - \frac{\gamma}{2}Var[R_p]= w'\mu -  \frac{\gamma}{2}w'Vw$$

Where $E$ and $Var$ denote the mean and variance of the uncertain portfolio rate of return $R_p = w'R_{T+1}$ to be realized in time $T + 1$ and $\gamma$ is the relative risk aversion coefficient.
The optimal portfolio weights will be:

$$w^* = \frac{1}{\gamma}V^{-1}\mu $$

Could I have a reference that proves this result? preferably a textbook that builds up to it.

Comment: I think Markowitz' 1959 book does, but it's a straightforward optimization that is easy if you look up the relevant matrix derivatives. I think I went through the math in another question here, but can't find it now.

Comment: Here: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/derivation-of-the-tangency-maximum-sharpe-ratio-portfolio-in-markowitz-portfol/8620#8620

Answer (score 3):

You do note require a sum up constraint that gives you that the weights sum up to 1?
Then the problem is equivalent to a maximization without constraints:
$$Z(\omega)=w'\mu -  \frac{\gamma}{2}w'Vw$$
then it holds that
$$\frac{dZ}{d\omega}=\mu-\gamma V\omega\overset{!}{=}0\\
\Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{\gamma}\mu=V\omega^*\\
\Leftrightarrow\omega^* = \frac{1}{\gamma}V^{-1}\mu $$