# Maximum Sharpe ratio and mean-variance optimization

Tags: portfolio-optimization, sharpe-ratio, markowitz

I want to understand why this holds:
$argmax_w ( \frac{\mu^T w}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}})=\Sigma^{-1}\mu $

I just found this post:
[Derivation of the tangency (maximum Sharpe Ratio) portfolio in Markowitz Portfolio Theory?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/derivation-of-the-tangency-maximum-sharpe-ratio-portfolio-in-markowitz-portfol?newreg=c13bb555d09944e3affd6babe48702dc)

In the process you exchanged the optimization problem for the optimal tangency portfolio with the optimization problem for the mean-variance portfolio:
$argmax_w (w^T\mu-\frac{1}{2}w^T\Sigma w )$

I want to understand why these optimization problems come to the same conclusion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first argmax is actually defined up to a constant multiplier: $argmax\left(\frac{\mu^Tw}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}}\right)=\lambda\Sigma^{-1}\mu$, where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary portfolio size scale.  In general, maximizing a scale-invariant ratio of the form $f(w)/g(w)$ can be done in conditional terms: $max(f)$ subject to $g=const$, or, using a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$, $max(f-\lambda g)$.  Formally, the optimality condition $\nabla(f/g)=0$ results in a collinearity of the gradients of $f$ and $g$ -- the same as in the conditional  maximum with a Lagrange multiplier.  The arbitrariness of the $\lambda$ scale disappears if there are constraints on the portfolio weights $w$ and/or transaction costs incurred when rebalancing the portfolio from its previous state.  This involves a more complicated, but still convex optimization problem, c.f. [this book.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119821320)

Comment: Thank you very much. My initial question was, which conditions must apply such that $argmax_w ( \frac{\mu^T w}{\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w}})=\Sigma^{-1}\mu $ $=$ $argmax_w (w^T\mu-\frac{1}{2}w^T\Sigma w )$ holds? In my case there is no budget contrain.

Comment: The condition for $argmax(\mu^Tw/\sqrt{w^T\Sigma w})=\Sigma^{-1}\mu$ is the normalization of the weights in the form $w^T\Sigma w=\mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu$, which is easily verified but has no deep meaning.  The solution of your original $argmax$ is defined up to a constant multiplier.