# Computation of tangency portfolio

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory

Good morning, I would like to solve the maximization problem that you can find at pag 23 of this source (http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/portfolioTheoryMatrix.pdf) in order to find the tangency portfolio. Unfortunately the algebra steps after the derivations of the first order conditions are not shown and I am not able to figure out how the result is obtained. Does someone have some advice?
( I attach a picture of the problem as a visual reference)
[image]

Comment: In answer to that question the same result is obtained through an unconstrained mean variance maximization, so the computation is different, I would like to understand how the algebra is done when we maximize the Sharpe ratio

Comment: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/68247/how-to-derive-the-weights-of-tangency-portfolio

Comment: and here is a nice video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=IhYhVW6IO7I