# Tangency portfolio negative maximum Sharpe ratio

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, sharpe-ratio, mean-variance

Suppose I have three assets: the market, factor A and factor B. The market is in excess returns of the risk free rate. The other two factors are long-short portfolios. I have net returns for these factors, since I deduct estimated transaction costs. The expected net returns for these factors are negative

The mean variance tangency portfolio produces a negative maximum Sharpe ratio in this case. How and why is this possible? Why is it not mean variance efficient to just allocate 100% of the weight in the excess market return?

I am looking forward hearing your answers.

Comment: What are net returns in a mean variance world? Do you mean net expected returns?  What do you mean by mean variance tangency portfolio? Any point at or above the mvp is Mean-variance-efficient (by definition)

Comment: Yes, I am refererring to net expected returns (i.e. taking transaction costs into account). With the mean variance tangency portfolio I am referring to the portfolio that is constructed using the weights that provide the largest Sharpe ratio (https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8594/derivation-of-the-tangency-maximum-sharpe-ratio-portfolio-in-markowitz-portfol provides the formula)

Comment: Might be helpful if you provided specific examples